# nodejs process.argv wild character does NOT expand on windows, in Macos works

Tags: node.js

I tried to use the std for example

```
 node arg_test.js *.txt
 process.argv.forEach(function (val, index, array) { 
 if(index >1) 
 input_file_names.push(val);})
```

And getting `argv[2]="*.txt"` instead of getting the file names ending in `".txt;`

is there any other package that expands the wildchars

Appreciate your help